# Fixed navbar list items not working

Tags: html, responsive-design, sass, navbar, fixed-width

I have this navbar: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rickzanutta/pen/JdGtz).
This is a fixed navbar, and I want that over 980px has a fixed width(in px), but I don't know why the last list item goes under the navbar.

```
<header class="" role="banner">
 <nav role="navigation">
  <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo"></a>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#" class="current">hi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">there</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">have</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">problem</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="nav-toggle">&#x2261;</span>
</nav>
```

Comment: there is not enough space for your floated item to be on the same line as the rest.. increasing your `nav` item to `885px` fixes this.. or you could decrease the width of your items

Comment: The last list item does not have the same padding and the same size...there is a space on the last part of the navbar, but i want that the ul takes all the space

Answer (score 1):

Check this helps you out: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/IoGvl

Starting at line 52 in your css you had

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  nav[role=navigation] {
    width: 882px;
    margin: 0 30px;
  }
```

but this isn't wide enough to hold your menu items. In my edited pen I changed the width to 970px

**EDIT**

> I want that every list item has the same size, and the navbar itself
>   mantain its margin-right and margin-left 30px

Check my pen now: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/IoGvl
The root of your problem is still that there wasnt' enough space to fit everything.

You have a left and right margin of 30px on the nav element itself, the nav-logo, the left and right padding of 2em on the ul, left hand borders on each li, plus the width of each li > a

If I'm understanding your description correctly, increasing the nav width to 888 px seems to help. Had you figured the 1 x 6 px width for the left hand borders of the list items into your calculations?

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3654340, please check my comments above

Comment: thanks, I didn't noticed the 1 x 6px width of the li items! is there a way to remove the remaining space for the last list item(without break its position)? @DavidTaiaroa

Comment: I'm not sure which space you are referring to @user3654340 . Another option would be change the width of the li > a elements from 131 to 130px . see http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/DneJv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! resolved with this: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/FkihJ) . All I have done was to wrap the nav in a  element and giving it padding: 0 30px to create a fixed nav(on a certain breakpoint).

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS Added:

```
@media only screen and(min-width: 980px) {
  header {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
}
```